# Add multiple row in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am a new user, I'm working with **jqGrid** plugin, I wanted to know if it was possible to add several rows at once and then save at the end.

---

I would like to add several lines and end with a button to save all..The following code:

```
    //for edit all    
    $("#list2").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager2', {
        caption: "Modifica", buttonicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
        onClickButton: function () {
            var ids = $('#list2').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length + 1; i++) {
                $('#list2').jqGrid('editRow', ids[i], true);
            }
        }
    });

    //for save all 
    $("#list2").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager2', {
        caption: "Salva", buttonicon: "ui-icon-disk",
        onClickButton: function () {
            var ids = $('#list2').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length + 1; i++) {
                $('#list2').jqGrid('saveRow', ids[i], false, 'PerformCRUDAction');
            }
        }
    });

  //add several rowa
 $("#list2").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager2', {
        caption: "Add", buttonicon: "ui-icon-add",
        onClickButton: function () {
            $("#list2").addRowData("Codice", {}, 'last');
         }
    });
```

through this function(jquery), I added the lines, but does not let me edit. I can only change the first only the first

Comment: I believe the answer is yes, although it would be helpful if you provided more information such as how exactly you are adding and saving the rows.